# Django: inspectdb doesn't generate all of my tables into models?

Tags: python, django, database, pycharm, inspectdb

I have a file - "codemets.db", which contains a lot of tables and data for my project. Some of the tables are:

```
- auth_group    
- auth_group_permissions    
- auth_user    
- auth_user_groups     
- ...   
- mappingapp_coordinates    
- ...
```

I am using PyCharm to create a new app on Django. I am trying to use the already existing database "codemets.db" and I am trying to auto-generate the tables into models. I am using the following commands:

```
python manage.py syncdb    
python manage.py inspectdb > models.py    
python manage.py makemigrations   
python manage.py migrate
```

However, I am getting all of the models for the tables only until the mappingapp_coordinates. 
For mappingapp_coordinates and the others after that, there are no models. Can someone help me with that? How can I generate all of my tables into models?

My second problem is:
when I open the app on the admin page I can see the tables (only the tables that have been generated into models), but there is no content from the database in them (they are empty). How can I put the data from my database into my app?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you included your apps in installed_apps in settings ?

Comment: Yes, I did. My app is called "prototype".

    INSTALLED_APPS = (
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        'prototype',
    )